# Login only to YouTube and not Gmail using same account

Tags: gmail, youtube

I want to leave my media PC without a password, for anyone in my house to use, which means I want to log into my YouTube account and leave my session open but I also don't want just anyone to be able to open my email account from this open session. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid not. Logging in to your Google Account gives access to all of the services you use there.

None of the alternatives are very convenient.

- Create a separate account purely for YouTube
- Set up some sort of kiosk mode that keeps the browser from going to a different site
- Use something like OpenDNS to keep from anyone from going to a different site, but you'll need to change it back to use it normally

Comment: Thanks! Thats what I was afraid of

Answer (score -1):

Set up some sort of kiosk mode that keeps the browser from going to adifferent site